# MockMvc POST Junit test returning HttpMessageNotReadableException

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, junit, mockmvc

Currently writing a unit test with MockMVC in order to test my controller.
The controller itself works fine but I am struggling to create a test to prove this.

Below I have created a simplified example to recreate the issue.

MyController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/controller")
public class TestController {

private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

/**
 * Resets the system including re-creation of the actor system and reload of
 * application configuration
 *
 * @param testObject
 * @return
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/testPost", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public void test(@RequestBody TestObject testObject) {


}
```

My Test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestController.class})
public class TestControllerTest {

private MockMvc mockMvc;
private final static ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

public TestControllerTest() {

}

@Test
public void testJSONPost() throws Exception {

    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new TestController()).setMessageConverters(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter()).alwaysDo(print()).build();
    mockMvc.perform(post("/controller/testPost").content(MAPPER.writeValueAsString(new TestObject(Long.MIN_VALUE, "value")))
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

When the Test runs I am given a 400 http response. Any insight that you could provide would be of benefit, thanks.

Comment: did you use `andDo(print())` to see what was happening?

Comment: can you share TestObject ?